# regex matching expression notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am really having trouble with regex using notepad++:

For any single word following an equal sign (=), place what follows the equal sign in quotes.
eg: `a = bcd` becomes `a = "bcd"`

This is what I have but it is giving me problems:

```
s/=\([^" >][^ >]*\)/="\1"/g
```

*** I am using the regex to search through a word document in Notepad++

Comment: Are you saying you're using Perl style regular expressions in notepad++, or that you're using notepad++ to create a perl script?

Comment: Your specs and results don't match.  You said, "place what follows the equal sign in quotes," but there's a whitespace after the "=" in `a = bcd` that your desired result doesn't include.  Did you mean "place non-whitespace characters following the equal sign in in quotes" or place all equal-sign-following characters within quotes?

Comment: If you need to provide more information about your question, update your question. Don't ask the same question three times!

Comment: actually that other post is a completely different question.

Comment: [No, it's really not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379732/perl-regex-assistance). You've got three posts asking the same two related questions, all of which are "subpar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Search: `(=\s*)(\w+\b)`
Replace: `$1"$2"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$searchText =~ s/(\w* *\= *)(\w*)/$1"$2"/g;
```

You should be specific about what is a word and what isn't and other constraints

Answer (score 0):

To place quotes around anything unquoted after equals in Notepad++ using a regex:

Find What: `=\s*([^"]*)$`
Replace With: `= "\1"`

Comment: Kind of I am trying.... I am to create quotations surrounding any word following an equal sign

Comment: @BobSmithsfield - Any word, all words (individually or collectively)?  Will there be more than one word?

Comment: any words and all words after an equal sign

Comment: By checking for quotes in the regex, you can run the search and replace multiple times without wrapping quoted text in more quotes.